# Parsing Json with no tags to bind to win 8 grid

Tags: json, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am trying to parse this json script.

```
{
    "Component1": {
        "Parameter1": "A",
        "Parameter2": "12.00"
    },
    "Component2": {
        "Parameter1": "B",
        "Parameter2": "13.00"
    },
    "Component3": {
        "Parameter1": "C",
        "Parameter2": "14.00"
    },
    "Component4": {
        "Parameter1": "D",
        "Parameter2": "15.00"
    },
    "Component5": {
        "Parameter1": "E",
        "Parameter2": "16.00"
    },
    "Component6": {
        "Parameter1": "F",
        "Parameter2": "17.00"
    },
    "Component7": {
        "Parameter1": "G",
        "Parameter2": "18.00"
    },
    "Component8": {
        "Parameter1": "H",
        "Parameter2": "17.00"
    },
    "Component9": {
        "Parameter1": "I",
        "Parameter2": "17.00"
    },
    "Component10": {
        "Parameter1": "J",
        "Parameter2": "17.00"
    },
    "Component11": {
        "Parameter1": "K",
        "Parameter2": "18.00"
    }
}
```

Now the component has 2 values to it.The weird thing about the snippet is the component doesn't have  a tag but its values have a tag and each component is represented by a tile in gridview.

I can parse parameter 1 and parameter2 using switch ,but how can I parse component name without a tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Web extensions](http://procbits.com/2011/04/21/quick-json-serializationdeserialization-in-c) and the JavaScriptSerializer to convert it into a dictionary of type (string, dynamic), so basically you will get a list of KeyValuePair< string,dynamic> such that you can do:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> kvp in deserializedDictionary)
{
    kvp.Key //this is your "ComponentX"
    kvp.Value.Parameter1 //this is the value in Parameter1
    kvp.Value.Parameter2 //this is the value in Parameter2
}
```

Then you can do whatever you want with them.